# Tell compiler about subclass -polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

If I have a baseclass Base and a subclass Sub, and in the subclass have a memberfunction that doesnt exist in the superclass - how do I tell the compiler its there?

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:

};

class Sub : public Base {

public:
    void printFromSub() {
        cout << "I am not inherited ;-)" << endl;
    }
};


int main() {

   Sub sub;
   Base* base;

   base = &sub;
   base->printFromSub(); // not possible at compile-time

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast to derived class.

If you are sure that `base` points to an object of the derived class, then you can use `static_cast`.

```
static_cast<Sub*>(base)->printFromSub();
```

If you aren't sure, then you'll need a runtime check.

```
Sub* p = dynamic_cast<Sub*>(base);
if (p) p->printFromSub();
```

Comment: Why suggest using `static_cast` even **if** the OP _thinks_ they know what it is?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Because then you don't need RTTI?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: just a small question - what `OP` stands for?

Comment: Orthopedic Pickle or if you prefer Original Poster - the person asking the question.